# How to group two query that have already been grouped

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I am creating a chat system and i have two queries: The first query selects the Max(id) meaning **the last message that has been received or sent by the member that is connected and that has not yet been read**  and the second selects **the last message that has been received or sent by the member that is connected whether it has been read by the other member or not**. Those messages are group by users as long as the users is not the one connected

First query

```
    SELECT MAX(`id`)   AS id, `from_id`, `to_id`,  `sent`, `read_statu` FROM `ojm_chat` WHERE

CASE 
WHEN `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`!='$id_ojm_peoples' 
END 

AND (`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND (is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))
```

Second query

```
SELECT MAX(`id`)   AS id, `from_id`, `to_id`,  `sent`, `read_statu` FROM `ojm_chat` WHERE 

    CASE 
    WHEN `from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`>='0' 
    END 




    AND 


    (`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

    AND  

    (is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

    GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))
```

In order to make this two query one, I united them using a **UNION**

```
    SELECT MAX(`id`)   AS id, `from_id`, `to_id`,  `sent`, `read_statu` FROM `ojm_chat` WHERE

CASE 
WHEN `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`!='$id_ojm_peoples' 
END 

AND (`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND (is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))




UNION




SELECT MAX(`id`)   AS id, `from_id`, `to_id`,  `sent`, `read_statu` FROM `ojm_chat` WHERE 

CASE 
WHEN `from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' THEN `read_statu`>='0' 
END 




AND 


(`from_id`='$id_ojm_peoples' OR `to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples')  

AND  

(is_deleted!='$id_ojm_peoples' AND is_deleted >=0)   

GROUP BY (IF(`to_id`='$id_ojm_peoples', `from_id`, `to_id`))
```

**PROBLEM**

However this did not group the users with their Id  but it rather gave me the users from the first query and then the users from the second query without grouping the users together. This is the output of the query above.

[image: Contact List]

As you can see some users appear twice instead of ONCE (grouped).

**Questions**
Please how to correctly Group this ? Each query have already been grouped once. Is there a way to group them together ?

Thanks

Comment: What value(s) do you get from each SELECT when run independently?

Comment: @RickJames The first one gives me half of the result of the image you see above and the second one the other half0